# In a headline should I use "Isn't it time..." or "Is it time..."

Tags: grammaticality, questions, negation

I have headline and there is confusion over which is correct.  "Is it time to make the jump?" or "Isn't it time to make the jump?"

Comment: Both are grammatically correct, which one you should choose depends on what you want it to mean/what interpretation you are trying to get across. Can please you edit the question to add a paraphrasing of the intended meaning?

Comment: As the second version is rhetorical, it suggests that the article will say that it is, in fact, the time to make the jump.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin: Ain't it just?

Comment: @Yosef Baskin: My above comment is simply a common colloquial "rhetorical question" that expresses emphatic agreement rather than a request for information or confirmation. If instead I'd said **Is it?**, that would normally be understood as either a request for justification, or a refutation.

Comment: 'Isn't it time to ... ?' is far more hectoring than 'Is it time to ... ?'

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: I'm sure if you asked the average parent what's the most irritating thing their kids say during car journeys they'd say it's ***Are we there yet?***, not ***Aren't we there yet?***

Comment: @FF They've surprisingly not mastered the art of hectoring. 'Aren't we there yet?' contains a mildly cloaked accusation.

Answer (score 1):

Both phrases are rhetorical, but they lead the reader to a different assumed opinion. Saying "Is it time..." would be interpreted as a more genuine question, leaving open the possibility that the answer would be "No, not yet." Saying "Isn't it time..." would be interpreted as if the author strongly believes that the time has definitely come, and even implies an expression of exasperation or frustration that the action has not occurred yet.